# Understanding diagonal search of 8 queen puzzle

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, search

I was solving the [8 queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) problem and tried to look through the internet for comparison solutions to see how my solutions compared to others. I found one very small brute force solution that confused me. And I was wondering if anyone care to explain how the diagonal comparison actually works?

```
void solve(int n, int col, int *hist)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    if (col == n)
    {
        print_solution(n, hist);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < col && !(hist[j] == i || abs(hist[j] - i) == col - j))
            j++;
        if (j < col)
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        hist[col] = i;
        solve(n, col + 1, hist);
        i++;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int hist[8];

    solve(8, 0, hist);
}
```

The code in particular `I have` problem visualizing is:

```
abs(hist[j] - i) == col - j)
```

From what I understand it checks the diagonals but I don't see it.

Comment: Go through it by hand, using pen and paper. (That is what I would have to do to explain it to you, so you can do that too.)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog its passed in by main. int hist[8] e.g. a history buffer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i tried and the numbers dont make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first loop condition is `j < col`, the right hand side of this condition is positive. `i` corresponds to the current row being checked, and `hist[j]` is the row of the queen on the `j`-th column. Thus this checks if the two points `(hist[j], j)` and `(i, col)` lie on either a "forward-slash" ( / ) or "back-slash" ( \ ), diagonal, by checking if the horizontal and vertical distances are equal. The `abs` is to allow both cases to be checked in one go.